# Why gdb switched to home directory?

Tags: gdb

Suppose the current directory is /home/xxx/test, there is a text file named "test.txt" which contains a single word "hello", and a file named "test.cpp" is as following,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        char cwd[1024];
        getcwd(cwd, 1024);
        cout << cwd << endl;

        string s;
        ifstream i("test.txt");
        if (!i.good())
                cout << "Can't open test.txt" << endl;

        i >> s;
        i.close();

        cout << s << endl;

        return 0;
}

test> g++ test.cpp
test> ./a.out
/home/xxx/test
hello
test> gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/xxx/test/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/xxx/test/a.out
/home/xxx
Can't open test.txt


Program exited normally.
(gdb) pwd
Working directory /home/xxx/test.
(gdb) shell pwd
/home/xxx
```

My question is why gdb switched to home directory which yields 'test.txt' can't be found?
Why 'pwd' and 'shell pwd' give different result?

Thanks.

Comment: gdb by itself shouldn't do that.  Does it happen with "gdb -nx"?  This disables your .gdbinit.  Also, the discrepancy between gdb and the shell's notion of pwd is odd.  I wonder why that is.  You should show the result of "pwd" before running gdb.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your hints here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'cd ~' in my .cshrc, this is the root cause for the difference between 'shell pwd' and 'pwd'.

After remove it, all the problems are resolved.

Thanks.